# How to write a relative path for SQLite connection in java?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, netbeans, relative-url

I am setting up an SQLite connection in Java in Netbeans. When I am writing the absolute path in the connection.java file, it works just fine. How do I write this as a relative path so that I can share the project with others as well?

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/sparshbohra/Desktop/214/214-project/src/baby/pluto/RoomBookingDatabase_V1.1.db");
```

This is what the folder looks like:

[image]

I am getting an error when I use the following link as a path:
"jdbc:sqlite:/RoomBookingDatabase_V1.1.db"

Comment: Have you tried putting the .db file in the classpath?

Comment: @Sara I have added the sqlitejdbc-v056.jar file to the library already. Is that what you are referring to by classpath?

Comment: I get the following error when I use the relative path: opening db '/RoomBookingDatabase_V1.1.db' read-only file system

Comment: try changing the properties of that file... remove the read-only property of that file

Comment: try putting it under a folder named resources

Comment: could you give a step by step approach instead? I am really confused as to how to change from read-only to read-write. I am using DB browser for sqlite. what will putting the database file under a resource folder do and where do I create the folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232266/discussion-between-sara-and-saucypanda).